# Wrong Image Link from the Picture Picker

Tags: android

Hy!

I have a Image Picker and the the problem is that i always get **wrong path** to the selected picture.

Code:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI), 1);
    ....
    @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    Log.e("XXX",uri.getPath());
        }
```

Log:

05-26 18:42:24.766: ERROR/XXX(3290): /external/images/media/2

The right link should be /scdard/test.jpg

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the link below:

[Image path](http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-file-path-of-gallery-image)

Hope it Helps!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `getPath()`. Instead, use a `Cursor` to get the path, something like this:

```
String[] proj = { MediaColumns.DATA };
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, proj, null, null, null);
int col_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
cursor.moveToFirst();
String path = cursor.getString(col_index);
```